# Expected an identifier and instead saw

Tags: javascript, angularjs

JSLint show me this message: "Expected an identifier and instead saw ']'."
This is my first time using Javascript.Her is my Code:

```
       (function () {
"use strict";
  }
    ());

    angular.module('Umfrage', 'Auswertung'[])
        .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', function ($scope, $log, $http) {
            $scope.vorname =  [];
            $scope.umfrageData = [];


            $scope.test = function () {
                $log.log($scope.vorname);
            };



                $scope.submitForm = function (data) {
                $scope.umfrageData.push(data);
                $http.post("http://localhost:8080/Auswertung")


                $http.get("http://localhost:8080") 
                .success(function (response) {$scope.umfrageData = response; });
                $log.log($scope.umfrageData);
            };

        }]);
```

Comment: You forgot a comma after `'Auswertung'`

Comment: @lyschoening. Almost corect. 'Auswertung' should be an item of the array

Comment: @Sprottenwels You're right. I only looked at the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

`angular.module('Umfrage', 'Auswertung'[])`

is creating a module, named 'Umfrage'. The second parameter should be an array, holding string items that match names of module which you would like to declare as a dependency of the module you're creating.

Thus, this would be correct, assuming that there is a module named 'Auswertung'

`angular.module('Umfrage', ['Auswertung'])`

See [**module API**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)